# Unable to add IBOutlet in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I'm trying to add an IBOutlet in swift but I only have the option to add an action.

**Here is an image of what I'm talking about.**

[image]]

Is there any way I can fix this?

[I can't change connection type either.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Slmk4.png)

Comment: remove view controller class name, close Xcode completely and restart Xcode and reassign view controller class name.

Comment: Did you assigned UIViewController to more than one View ?

Comment: Maybe is because you are dragging it to the function viewDidLoad. Have you tried to drag the outlet in a blank space?

Comment: Sometimes the assistant editor won't work. Just create the @IBoutlet manuallly in your code and then connect it in Interface Builder.

Comment: @celiux, I tried dragging it to other places and I still get the same problem

Comment: @Paulw11 if I put in the the IBOutlet manually it will not function properly. I don't know why

Comment: Clarify "doesn't work properly".  I never use the assistant editor. I always create the @IBOutlet manually and then connect it in Interface Builder.  Have you set the custom class for your scene properly? I notice that your class selection on the right is "manual", so perhaps you haven't set the scene class.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the cause of the problem. I explain you with more detail in an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because you are trying to connect an outlet from the Interface Builder to a non-corresponding View Controller file, so that's why it only gives you the option to add an Exit action. Just make sure that you are in the same View Controller both in the IB and in the Assistant Editor.

P.S. I recommend you renaming properly every view controller so it will be easier to avoid this (make sure to change the name not only in the class but also in the IB). You can use the cmd + click when selecting the class name on the code and click on `Rename...` to change all at once. If you already changed it in your code, you have also to do it then manually in the IB, selecting the corresponding one from the drop-down menu of the Identity Inspector:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the connection type or one more thing you can do. you can do this. By opening connection inspector and drag the outlet into view controller like shown in image..

[image]

To Change Connection Type

[image]

Comment: How do I change the connection type?
By the way, By opening the connection inspector and dragging the outlet Xcode won't let me add the outlet

Comment: I updated my question showing that I can't change the connection type

Answer (score 0):

Try ctrl dragging it from the text on the left ([image])

Answer (score 0):

Restart your Xcode and try to connect @IBOutlet

Comment: You could use a comment instead of an answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same class in your view controller (call it View Controller.swift)

Comment: didn't seem any addition to existing answer and this also look a better comment

Comment: I fail to see your purpose in posting this comment

Comment: i was reviewing posts and your post seems as a comment and nothing better than post which is already exists

Comment: Okay. But what did you achieve by posting this comment on my answer ?

Comment: read the faq and usage of site, it is to learn for everyone and answer and comments needs to be distinguished, the site is managed by community and moderator, you are just started and if you don't know the site rule then that's the goal towards the comment. consider your self when you ask question or look for a question and you get one liner answer without explanation how you feel that.

Comment: Okay. Sorry I'm still new here